# Making Python reread a file while the program is running

Tags: python

I am having trouble writing code for this program:

```
#opening a file

addressbook = open("h:/A453/Address Book/AddressBook1.txt","r+")

line = addressbook.readline()

searchdata = input("Please enter the surname you are looking for ")

if searchdata in line:
    print(line)
```

All of the above work but it only reads the bottom line of text in the file when I run it. I have researched this on the web but have not found anything useful or understandable. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `addressbook.seek(0)` will put the file cursor at the beginning again. You can also do `addressbook.seek( addressbook.tell() - len(line) )` to seek one line backwards from where you are now. But i'm unsure of what you're asking here, do you want to re-read the entire file again? and why so? You've already stored the actual line that you're comparing against in the variable `line`?

Comment: You're reading just one line from the file. If there are more than one line you need to use readlines() or read them sequentially in a loop and search in each line separately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, you are using `.readline()` which reads only one line from the file to read the whole file you have 2 options: `.read()` or `.readlines()`

**.read() method**
It reads the contents of the file in one go and returns a string with all the escape characters and spaces preserved.

**.readlines()**
It reads the file and returns a list of contents of the file whose elements are `split()` at each newline.

```
#opening a file

addressbook = open("h:/A453/Address Book/AddressBook1.txt","r+")

line = addressbook.read()

searchdata = input("Please enter the surname you are looking for ")

if searchdata in line:
    print(line)
```

Comment: If I put in Vickers, which is on of the surnames in my file, it outputs everything, just separated. How can I just make the details of Vickers be outputted only and not the others?